# Subtracting the previous qty to the current quantities

Tags: sql-server, computed-column

I have a table as:
[image]

Here I want to subtract the required Qty for a part from On Hand and then the result from the required for next sequence

Hoping to get this as a final result: [image]

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be wiht a window function. You need to partition correctly though.

```
insert into inventory
values
('A',1,10,3),
('A',2,10,2),
('B',1,5,3),
('B',2,5,2),
('B',3,5,2)

select 
   *, 
   Remaining = OnHand - sum(required) over (partition by Part order by OrderNo)
from inventory
```

Note, you seem to have miscalculated Part B in your expected results.